# Next JS API Routes add query on Client side

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, next.js, client-server

I am fetching IGDB api on server because I need to go through CORS. I am using async await connected to client side. Everything works fine but I need to pass query like '/?fields=cover.*,name;limit=50;' to https://api.igdb.com/v4/games  from client side, not from server. When I am adding a query to client side, it's still showing the query only from server. How I can pass this query from client side? This is my code:

*api/example.js*

```
import Cors from "cors";
import initMiddleware from "../../components/init-middleware";

const cors = initMiddleware(
    Cors({
        methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'OPTIONS'],
    })
)

const settings = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Client-ID': 'my_client-id',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer my_authorization',
    },

}

const remoteServerUrl = 'https://api.igdb.com/v4/games'


export default async function handler(req, res) {
    await cors(req, res)
    const response = await fetch(remoteServerUrl, settings);
    const data = await response.json()
    res.json(data)
}
```

*client side*

```
const settings = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Client-ID': 'my_client-id',
        'Authorization': 'Bearer my_authorization',
    },

const fetchData = async () => {
            let query = '/api/example/'
            const response = await fetch(query + HERE I WANT TO ADD QUERY, settings);
            const data = await response.json();
        }
```

**Edit:**
Status Code: 308 Permanent Redirect

*initMiddleware*

```
// Helper method to wait for a middleware to execute before continuing
// And to throw an error when an error happens in a middleware
export default function initMiddleware(middleware) {
    return (req, res) =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            middleware(req, res, (result) => {
                if (result instanceof Error) {
                    return reject(result)
                }
                return resolve(result)
            })
        })
}
```

Comment: Does string concatenation of queryString parameters not work? What have you tried?

Comment: It doesn't work, I have also tried: query += '?fields=cover.*,name;limit=50;'

Comment: When I add this query from server side, it works, but it doesn't from client side.

Comment: Does it not append to the request URL string, or does the request not work? Check the network tab in the browser's devtools to see what is actually requested.

Comment: In network tab I found Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/example/?fields=cover.*,name;limit=50;
Is this it?

Comment: Sure looks like it, and it seems the request URL is formed correctly. If this call is failing what is the status code and/or response?

Comment: Status Code: 308 Permanent Redirect

Comment: Do I have a badly configured server?

Comment: @DrewReese I still can't go through it. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Now I updated the post with code of initMiddleware function.

Comment: Sorry, I have pretty minimal exposure to Nextjs, and this bit is outside my wheelhouse.